# PHP - file_put_contents writes content multiple times

Tags: php

I have an extremely oversimplified logger function:

```
<?php
class Logger {
    public function __construct($logFile) {
        $this->logFile = $logFile;
    }

    public function log($message) {
        $message = date('c') . $message;
        file_put_contents($this->logFile, $message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        echo "it ran ";
    }
}
```

Calling it like this

```
$logger = new Logger('log.txt');
$logger->log("message");
echo "called the method";
```

causes the message to be written to the file exactly 3 times, instead of 1.

The code is outside of any loop, which is confirmed by echo statements, which get printed only once.

Also, if I simply run `file_put_contents()` function on place where I'd call the log method, it works fine and writes the content just once. So it might have something to do with my class, but no clue what.

EDIT: @Tommy: here is the log file content:
2014-09-26T07:24:51-04:00message2014-09-26T07:24:54-04:00message2014-09-26T07:24:54-04:00message

EDIT 2: I tried using die() function after calling the method, and then it did write the message just once. So I kept moving the die() through the code, and it starts writing the message 3 times after this exact line:

```
if (isset($_POST['create_account'])) {
    die;
```

Since there's a die below it, it shouldn't even matter what's in further code, right?

Wonder if it might be some sort of php bug, this is very stange. If I put the die() above this line, it will work fine and write the message just once.

Comment: There is nothing to suggest/force writing 3 times. Can you paste more code?

Comment: As above, there is something else causing this - the class above does not have anything that would cause multiple writes

Comment: Yeah there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Delete log file and show us the log after one execution of that code

Comment: Same happends to me... and review my code...yet for the same php function file_put_contents... it adds 3 times the same line. Did you find a solution CodeVirtuoso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly good chance that your code does a redirect or reload somewhere. This causes a new request to start, which wipes away the original echo but does not remove the one written to file. As a result it looks like it was echo'd once and written thrice. But really, it was echo'd thrice as well, just the other copies have been removed.

If you want to see what's going on, print part of the stack-trace into the log-file along with the message. You can see exactly on which line the message is created and during which function call.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue as per my experience is the index.php is being called twice. So, to fix:

- change the file name
- fix the index.php such that favicon.ico is missing!

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue as well, as answered by [[@Erik]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288307/erik), somewhere in your script there is a reload or redirect. In my case on was on live server in VS code (not in a production environment) and each time a file gets downloaded, it auto-reloads the script causing the file to be written multiple times. Disabling live server had the file written only once. Not sure if were running it locally as well but this may help!